# How to sort the dates using spark while generating xml?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-xml

I am trying to write an xml file by converting dataframes using some jax jar, but I need to sort. It's not sorting if I appply my sorting at dataframe-level because at the end I am writing a final dataframe using xml jar and call each object how can sort based on dates here?

```
 def generateChannel(ChannelList:Seq[Row]):Seq[Channel]={
  var uput:Seq[Uss]=Seq.empty[Uss]

         uList.foreach(x => {

        var uss: Uss = new Uss()

        uss.setAdd1(x.getAs[String]("_Ade1"))

        val Channel = new Channel
        val Channelrow = x.getAs[Row]("Channelnode")

        if (Channelrow !=null){

        Channel.setCode(Channelrow.getAs[String]("_TCode"))
        Channel.setEfdate(Channelrow.getAs[String]("_Efdate"))
        Channel.setExpdate(Channelrow.getAs[String]("_Expdate"))
             uss.getChannel.add(Channel)}
     uput=uput:+uss

      })
    uput
  }
```

how can I sort the `_Efdate` and `_Expdate`? using `dff.sortBy`? or any other way?

for eg: Channel.sortBy(x => (x._Efdate, x._Expdate))

like below ?

val sortUdf = udf { (xs: Seq[Row]) => xs.sortBy(_.getAsInt )
                                        .map{ case Row(x:java.sql.Date, y: Int) => (x,y) }}  ?

Comment: question wording,  input data code is not clear. there is no way to reproduce